# Choosing suitable structures

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I was given a problem and was wondering if there is some way to solve this rather than the method I have been using so far (unsuccessfully) which was to guess for ways it could work. Is there a better way to solve this type of problem?

Give a suitable structure such that a1 is false, a2 and a3 are true

(a.1) ∀x∀y∀z((P(x,y) ∧ P(y,z)) → P(x,z))

(a.2) ∀x∀y((P(x,y) ∧ P(y,x)) → x = y)

(a.3) ∀x∀y(P(a,y) → P(x,b))

I've tried defining P to be P = {(m,n) | m != n} or 2m = n but the first one always messes it up. How should I be solving this problem other than blind guessing?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: They're constants that must exist in the chosen domain

Comment: How about taking the domain $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with $P=\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$ and $a=b=4?$

Comment: Why does that make a.1 false? Can't P(x,z) be assigned either of those two and still be true?

Comment: If we assign $x=1$ and $y=2$ and $z=3$ then what? Is $P(x,y$ true? Is $P(y,z)$ true? Is $P(x,z)$ false?

Comment: Oh I see, so with the quantifiers I just need to give every P(x,y) every combination of {1,2,3,4} and see if it's a pair?  That makes sense!  Thank you so much!

Comment: But with $P$ interpreted as $\{ (m,n) \mid m \ne n \}$ you can falsify (a.1) ! Consider $1$ and $2$: we have that $1 \ne 2$ and $2 \ne 1$,while $1 \ne 1$ does not hold. Thus, $((1 \ne 2) \land (2 \ne 1)) \to (1 \ne 1)$ is false, and thus it is false that: $\forall x \ \forall y \ \forall z \  [((x \ne y) \land (y \ne z)) \to (x \ne z)]$

Comment: But of course this interpretation does not satisfy (a.2) and (a.3).

Comment: You should try to think what the axioms mean, and then try to think of what relations that you know satisfy these axioms. For example axiom 1 is something you must have encountered: It tells you that your relation is transitive. Axiom 2 is also something that you probably have encountered: It tells you that your relation is anti-symmetric. Do you know of a relation that has these two properties? Also what does axiom 3 say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a systematic way to attack such a problem would be to look at [tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux#First-order_logic_tableau). But you don't really need to learn the entire proof system. At heart, the idea is to *first* consider the formulas where your choices are constrained. For example, here we have three universal statements: $\forall x \forall y \forall z ((Pxy \land Pyz) \to Pxz)$, $\forall x \forall y ((Pxy \land Pyx) \to x=y)$, and $\forall x \forall y (Pay \to Pxb)$. The first we want to be false and the other two we want to be true.

The only way for a universal statement to be false is for there to be *some* element in the domain which makes it false. That is, we know that however our structure turns out, it has to have elements $u, v, w$ such that $(Puv \land Pvw) \to Puw$ is false. So we start to build the structure by putting such elements in the domain. We need $u, v, w$ with $u$ $P$-related to $v$, $v$ $P$-related to $w$, and $u$ **not** $P$-related to $w$. As long as these elements are there, the first universal statement will be false.

Then we consider the formulas which don't really constrain our choices much, the other two universals. The way to go about this is just to see if we have to add anything to the structure in order to satisfy these statements. Since they're both conditionals, we're in luck: we can satisfy them both vacuously. We just need our structure to have $Pxy \land Pyx$ false everywhere and $Pay$ false everywhere.

But hey, check it out, if we just add some elements named $a$ and $b$ to the domain and **no more** $P$-relations to the structure, we're done.

So our structure (call it $\mathbf{A}$) should have domain $A = \{u, v, w, a, b\}$ and the extension of $P$ should be $P^A = \{(u,v), (v,w)\}$. (And after completing this construction, you'll notice that there's nothing special about what the element $b$ is, you can take it to be $a, u, v$, or $w$, which should correspond to the solution(s) given in the comments.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you very much!